# load options via. jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load some data via. jquery

```
    $get_desc = "SELECT tekst_id,overskrift FROM rr_tekster WHERE beskrivelse_id = '". $_POST['beskrivelse_id'] ."' AND status = 1";
    $select = mysql_query($get_desc)or die(mysql_error());
    while($row_option = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row_option['tekst_id'].'">'.$row_option['overskrift'].'</option>';
    }   


$arr = array (
        'list_options' => $output
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

and my jquery looks like this

```
$.post(action, { beskrivelse_id:des_id }, function(data){                                   
                            $(load_div).fadeOut();
                            $(result).html('<select name="tekster">'+data.list_options+'</select>').fadeIn(500);

                    },'json');
```

THE "ERROR": {"list_options":null}

in firebug it gives me an null error in the output... i want it to show all rows in my database, rigtig now it should show me 3 rows..

but nothing .. :-/ why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need json for what you are trying to achieve:

```
$get_desc = "SELECT tekst_id,overskrift FROM rr_tekster WHERE beskrivelse_id = '". $_POST['beskrivelse_id'] ."' AND status = 1";
        $select = mysql_query($get_desc)or die(mysql_error());
        while($row_option = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
                $output .= '<option value="'.$row_option['tekst_id'].'">'.$row_option['overskrift'].'</option>';
        }       

echo $output;


$.post(action, { beskrivelse_id:des_id }, function(data){                                                               
                                                        $(load_div).fadeOut();
                                                        $(result).html('<select name="tekster">'+data+'</select>').fadeIn(500);

                                        });
```

Comment: yeah, that seems to work ... :o 
Now i just got some charset error/ bugs... :-/

its kinda of weird, cause I always used json_encode but this time it did't work.. spooky ...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be JSON-encoding an array, which would look like `[ ]` in the JSON-syntax. However, you're accessing it with the object-syntax (`data.list_options`). You could do:

```
$responseobj = new stdClass();
$responseobj->list_options = $output;
echo json_encode($responseobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

$output is NULL when your query returns no result, and you (not good!) not initialize $output at the beggining and you not check, if $output is empty or not in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with json_encode.  I could only get it to encode classes, so I had to instantiate an object and json_encode that object to return my data.